# Async / Await JS Catch not working in try/catch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch, ecmascript-2017

I have the bit of javascript below. Using async/await in our ES6 project. I have noticed that now all of a sudden a 404 response code isn't hitting the catch. In fact the .json() is also throwing a console error but still not hitting the catch. I would expect any error in the try to immediately throw and go to the catch block of code.

```
async getDash(projectId, projectUserId) {
  try {
    const events = (await this.apiHttp
      .fetch(`${projectId}/users/${projectUserId}/participant-event-dash`)).json();
    return events;
  } catch (e) {
    // fail back to local (dev testing)
    return (await this.http
      .fetch(`${this.appConfig.url}dist/api/query/json/partic-event-dash.json`)).json();
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is not part of ES6. It will (most likely) be part of the spec released next year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `json()` method is asynchronous, you should add one more `await`:

```
async getDash(projectId, projectUserId) {
  try {
    const events = await (await this.apiHttp
      .fetch(`${projectId}/users/${projectUserId}/participant-event-dash`)).json();
    return events;
  } catch (e) {
    // fail back to local (dev testing)
    return await (await this.http
      .fetch(`${this.appConfig.url}dist/api/query/json/partic-event-dash.json`)).json();
  }
}
```